# How to tell whether machine is on AD Domain when running as SYSTEM

Tags: environment-variables, active-directory, cmd.exe

I have a batch script run as the SYSTEM user, and I need to find out whether the machine is on an AD Domain or not. I don't know, or need to know, the AD Domain name, just whether it's on any AD Domain, or in a Workgroup.

Not running as system, I can use `%USERDNSDOMAIN%`, `%USERDOMAIN%`, `%LOGONSERVER%` etc. but these are not defined when running as SYSTEM.

I've also tried `DSQUERY`, but that isn't installed on all the machines, and `NET VIEW /DOMAIN` also didn't work.

Any ideas?

I need it to work in my cmd script, so something like a filename existing or not would be nice, or a registry setting.

Comment: It may be helpful to take a look at your CMD script - is it possible?

Comment: Im not sure what you are trying to accomplish...  FYI, just because a machine thinks its a part of a domain doesnt mean it actually is.  For example, you can join a machine from the domain, then remove it from AD.  The machine will not know it is no longer a part of AD.

Comment: @duDE I don't think my script would add any clarity, it's just a simple test I'm after; Keltari Just want to know if the machine thinks it's in a domain or not

Comment: @FrinkTheBrave: I see, no problem!

Comment: I am now checking the registry value: HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Domain which seems to be set to the AD Domain name if on a domain and blank if it is not on an AD Domain. Anyone forsee any problems with this?

Comment: Whether you think your script is simple or not, it would be more information that would clarify things for us. I did a quick web search and found "systeminfo | findstr /i "domain"". Have you tried that? For Powershell there's also these options: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74238703/powershell-script-to-check-if-a-computer-is-a-domain-controller-or-not